# suggestions for test class

Tags: apex, trigger

hii friends please suggest me  test class for this  below. i have also written one test class but showing error

```
Trigger RevenueWithoutST on Revenue__c (before insert,Before Update) {
    List<SCSCHAMPS__Appointment__c> appList;
    List<Revenue__c> revlist = new List<Revenue__c>();
    string eCode;
    date salaryDate;
    string category;
    string type;
    Integer month;
    Integer year;
    for(Revenue__c rev:Trigger.new){
        eCode=rev.ECode__c;
        salaryDate=rev.Salary_Processed_Month__c;
        month=rev.Salary_Processed_Month__c.month();
        year=rev.Salary_Processed_Month__c.year();
        category=rev.InvoiceCategory__c;
        type=rev.Invoice_Type__c;
        if(eCode!=null){
           appList =[select AvvasECode__c,Name_of_the_Candidate__c,Client_Name__c,Date_of_Onboarding__c,Last_Working_Date__c,Location__c from SCSCHAMPS__Appointment__c where AvvasECode__c=: ecode] ;
            for(SCSCHAMPS__Appointment__c app : appList){
               rev.Talent_Name__c= app.Name_of_the_Candidate__c;
               rev.Client_Name__c=app.Client_Name__c;
               rev.DOJ__c=app.Date_of_Onboarding__c;
               rev.Last_Working_Date__c=app.Last_Working_Date__c;
               rev.Location__c=app.Location__c;
            }
        }

        if((eCode!=null) && (category=='individual') &&(salaryDate!=NULL) ){
            List<Invoice__c> InvList;
            InvList=[select id,Name,Emp_Code__c,Invoice_Category__c,Sub_Total__c,Invoice_Date__c
                     from Invoice__c
                     where Emp_Code__c=: ecode
                      AND CALENDAR_MONTH(Invoice_Date__c)=:month
                      AND CALENDAR_YEAR(Invoice_Date__c)=:year ];
            System.debug('+++invoice'+InvList);
            FOR(Invoice__c inc : InvList){
              rev.Revenue_Without_ST__c=inc.Sub_Total__c;
            }
        }else if(eCode!=null && category=='consolidated'){
            List<Invoice_Line_Item__c> ILineList;
         // Invoice_Line_Item__c iline=new Invoice_Line_Item__c();
            ILineList=[select id,Name,Employee_Code__c,Total__c,Invoice_Date__c 
                       from Invoice_Line_Item__c
                       where Employee_Code__c=:ecode
                        AND CALENDAR_MONTH(Invoice_Date__c)=:month 
                        AND CALENDAR_YEAR(Invoice_Date__c)=:year ];
            for(Invoice_Line_Item__c IL : ILineList){
              rev.Revenue_Without_ST__c=IL.Total__c;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my  test class but if i am commenting on d below lines its getting saved but code coverage is 0. without comment itsw is showing the fields dont exist.

```
 @isTest
    public class testRevenue {
        static testMethod void testMethod1() {
            InvoiceCategory__c InvC = newInvoiceCategory__c(name = 'Test1');
            insert InvC;
            Invoice_Type__c InvT = new Invoice_Type__c(name = 'Test2'); 
            insert  InvT;
            Salary_Type__c SalT = new ISalary_Type__c(name = 'Test2'); 
            insert  SalT

            Test.StartTest();
                Revenue__c rev= new Revenue__c();
                rev.ECode__c='Test0';
                //InvoiceCategory__c invC = new InvoiceCategory__c
                //List<SelectOption> listInvCt = rev.InvoiceCategory__c();
                //List<SelectOption> listInvTy = rev.Invoice_Type__c();
                //List<SelectOption> listSalTy = rev.Salary_Type__c();
                rev.SelInvoiceCategory__c ='Test1';
                rev.SelInvoice_Type__c ='Test2';
                rev.SelSalary_Type__c ='Test3';
                rev.Salary_Processed_Month__c=system.today();
            Test.StopTest();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you update your question with the error message you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

You have written trigger on `Revenue__c` object but you are not doing any DML
operation in your test class.

First insert a `Revenue__c` record and see what data you need for your code coverage.

Try to first cover a  block code of trigger not all code at once.
You can try this and modify it as your requirement. This code is for your first if condition.

```
@isTest
public class testRevenue {
    static testMethod void testMethod1()  { 
        Revenue__c rev= new Revenue__c();

        rev.ECode__c='Test0';
        rev.Salary_Processed_Month__c = Data.today();
        rev.InvoiceCategory__c = 'individual';
        rev.Invoice_Type__c = 'Type';       

        SCSCHAMPS__Appointment__c appoint = SCSCHAMPS__Appointment__c( );  
        appoint.Name_of_the_Candidate__c = 'candidate';
        appoint.Client_Name__c = 'client';
        appoint.Date_of_Onboarding__c = date.today();
        appoint.Last_Working_Date__c = date.today().adddays(-2);
        appoint.Location__c = 'location';
        appoint.AvvasECode__c = rev.ECode__c;
        insert appoint;

        Test.StartTest();      

        insert rev;

        Test.StopTest();

        rev = [Select id, Talent_Name__c From Revenue__c  where ECode__c = 'ECode__c'] ;
        System.assertEquals('candidate', rev.Talent_Name__c );
    }
}
```

Comment: Test methods that do not assert data validity are meaningless as they just trigger something to happen and not test that what actually happened was correct